# WPF Style.Trigger

Tags: wpf, resources, triggers, styles, expander

Somebody can tell me why this trigger doesn't work:

```
<!--Style-->
<Style x:Key="Test" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="false"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<!-- Syle applyed in expander -->
<Expander Header="Expander" Margin="40,89,118,0" Name="expander1" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Height="100" Margin="86,0,-8,-58" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />        
            </Grid>
        </Expander>

<!-- Code Behind -->
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.expander1.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

I try in other ways, but without success..
Have another way to collapse content when expander is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the style to the Expander like:

```
<Expander Header="Expander" Name="expander1" Style="{StaticResource Test}" >
...
</Expander>
```

If you don't want to explicitly apply the style, then don't declare `x:Key="Test"`, and all Expanders in the same scope as that resource (i.e. all Expanders in that particular Page if you declared `x:Key="Test"` in `<Page.Resources>`) will inherit that style.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, but i forgot the block of code that you mentioned.
I put a reference in Style tag, and, the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but i forgot the block of code that you mentioned. I put a reference in Style tag, and, the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the user clicks on the expander, the IsExpanded "local value" is set, which takes precedence over the trigger. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for more information about dependency property value precedence.

A possible solution will be to rewrite the entire Expander control template, adding a trigger to the template's triggers that hides the "expanded" zone if `IsEnabled` is false (the default template only does this if `IsExpanded` is false). You can get the default template using Blend, by adding an expander on a Window, right click on it and select Edit Template > Edit a copy in the contextual menu.